# Keyboard need to open automatic and ready to type when activity start in jetpackCompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, user-input, wear-os, android-softkeyboard

Here I am trying to open keyboard automatic when activity get started in JetpackCompose, but I am not getting any ways to achieve this success and getting the error below:

[image]

As **I study more and I found that I cannot use `focusRequester.requestFocus()` outside of clickable method**, so here I want to know any other way I can achieve this success or cannot open input keyboard automatic, need reason or solution. Thanks.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun UIEnterName() {
   
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) 
    {
       focusRequester.requestFocus()
       keyboardController?.show()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your logs suggest that you need to use/apply focusRequester for any event(like request focus for textfield or any kind of component) if you want to request focus. Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to call `keyboardController?.show()` in `LaunchedEffect()`, it will show-up directly when you request focus for any textfield. Checkout below sample code:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

//Need to hide keyboard when we navigate or pop back
DisposableEffect(key1 = Unit, effect = {
    onDispose {
      keyboardController?.hide()
    }
})

LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
})

BasicTextField(
    value = title,
    onValueChange = {
        // Your code
    },
    maxLines = 1,
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    modifier = Modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .padding(top = 40.dp, start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    textStyle = //textstyle,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Next
    ),
    cursorBrush = SolidColor(ComposeTheme.colors.primary)
)
```

This code will open keyboard when this screen launches and hide keyboard when we navigate or pop back

Comment: Thanks @Megh for the response , this help me a lot but here problem occurred when back press and again coming to same screen keyboard sometime it's not opening , so i try many methods to check what's issue was and i found focusRequester.captureFocus() and i put this at last and work good as i needed ..